# Nested ListBox Size - truncating data - solution file test app link included

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a nested listboxes in a window with a MaxHeight.  The nested listbox data is getting truncated (see image, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10557283/truncatedlist.png)  In the image linked there should be some more fields, and some buttons at the bottom.

Here is the FULL SOLUTION!  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10557283/TestListBoxApp.zip

```
<Window x:Class="MapLibrary.Geocoding.FieldTranslator"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FieldTranslator" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        SizeToContent="Width"
        MaxHeight="600"
        >

        <ListBox x:Name="FieldsListBox" Margin="10,10,10,10"  Background="Beige" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShapeFileName}" FontWeight="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Button Width="100" Content="←" />
                            <Button Width="100" Content="→"/>
                            <Button Width="100" Content="Clear"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding outputfields }" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <ListBox Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding inputfields }" Grid.Column="2" />
                        </Grid>

                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the outer ListBox? The screenshot doesn't show it iterating anything.

Comment: Its a list of objects, each object has two lists of strings {inputfields and outputfields} and a name.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is being truncated from the picture.   In general if the text is bigger than the container then the text will be truncated.  I you want the text to wrap then set the TextWrapping property.